# How to ovelap a sound with its self?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

I am new to sounds in Xcode and I wish to play a sound repeatedly, whether it is playing already or not. Eg. I have three lasers which are being shot, and I wish for the laser sound to be played three times simultaneously, without waiting for each one to finish playing. How do I achieve this using `AVAudioPlayer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
AVAudioPlayer *laserSound1  = .........
laserSound1.numberOfLoops = 2; //plays three times simultaneously
[laserSound1 play];

 AVAudioPlayer *laserSound2  = .........
laserSound2.numberOfLoops = 2;//plays three times simultaneously
[laserSound2 play];

AVAudioPlayer *laserSound3  = .........
laserSound3.numberOfLoops = 2;//plays three times simultaneously
[laserSound3 play];
```